# Overflow in div tag doesn't work

Tags: html

I have a div tag with fixed width. Now i want that if there is a condition of overflow then text should go to next line automatically. I used overflow:auto but its giving a horizontal scroll bar.

My code is:

```
 <div id="header_area">
    <div class="leftAlign" style="float:left;width:70%;padding:3px;">
        BMT-DTL-CUSTOMER
    <div class="rightAlign" style="float:left:width:30%;padding:3px;color:#FFFF00;overflow:block;">
        Version 1.1
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you used overflow:block instead of auto. you can also use overflow-x or overflow-y. however your Div block is not closed.

Comment: I think word-wrap of css property is solution. [Refer](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap) this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One div tag is not closed, Other than that your code seems fine to me. I think the problem may be with the Outer Containers. Please check the width of outer containers, may be outer containers have lesser width than inner containers.